# Does UseSynchronizationContext=false mean I have to be thread safe?

Tags: wpf, wcf, duplex-channel

This is about a WCF duplex service with NetTcpBinding.

I just added the UseSynchronizationContext=false parameter to my ServiceBehavior attribute which stops things freezing up when calling Close() on the callback channel on the service side.

However does this mean I now have to be thread safe in my WPF window? Since I might get a callback operation while clicking a button at the same time on two different threads right?

Comment: I did some tests, it seems that the callback operation is marshalled back onto the SynchronizationContext of the window on the client side which makes sense.